# Is there a way to override Ruby's default string interpolation behavior with a method?

Tags: ruby

Neither `to_s` nor `to_str` appear to get called when an object is referenced inside a double-quoted string interpolation. For example:

```
# UPDATE: This example actually works as expected. See update below.
class Foo
  def to_s
   'foo'
  end

  def to_str
    to_s
  end
end

"#{Foo.new}" # result: "#<Foo:0x007fb115c512a0>"
```

I don't suppose there's something I can do to make the return value `"foo"`?

**UPDATE**

Apologies, but this code actually works. Mistake in another piece of code.

Comment: Even though it was based on misinformation, the question itself does provide some good value to people who don't know about `to_s`. So...well done! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With what version of Ruby are you seeing these results? This works correctly for me with Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.8.6:

```
class Foo
  def to_s
   'hi mom'
  end
end

puts "#{Foo.new}"
#=> hi mom
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not returning a string. Remove the `puts`, since `to_s` needs to RETURN a string representation, not output it.

*Note: this response is based on a previous version of the question where the `to_s` method had the code `puts "foo"`.*

Comment: He *is* returning something (as it's impossible not to return something in Ruby), it's just not what he wants. It's actually curious that interpolation ignores `to_s` when it returns `nil`.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall [`nil.to_s` is ""](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s).

Comment: @steenslag Which is not `"#<Foo:0x007fb115c512a0>"`, hence the `nil` return value being ignored.

Comment: Sorry, the `puts` was actually a typo. Corrected in the example. The fundamental issue is that neither `to_s` nor `to_str` are getting called in the interpolation.

Comment: @JeffLee Yes, they were getting called. When you had the `puts` in there it was returning `nil` and **if** your `to_s` does not return a string it is ignored. As shown in my answer, once you use the code you actually have in the question now, everything works as intended and the question is no longer valid. :)